# using MS exchange API to create appointment

Tags: asp.net, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am creating appointment using MS exchange API as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx

and it is working fine.

But it does not show in Resource/Location Calendar means i am specifying the Conference room using Location property but didn't work  then i tried

```
appointment.Resources.Add(new Attendee("cr1@domain.com"));
```

but it subject is showing only my domain Username(credential i am using for API) but in my calendar it is showing everything means subject,body.

what is the right way to show appointment in conference room calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when a CR accepts an invite, it replaces the subject with the organizer's name.  This is a configuration setting for the room.  It can be changed using the `Set-CalendarProcessing` cmdlet.  The parms you need will be `-DeleteSubject` and `-AddOrganizerToSubject.`  Setting the first to `$false` will keep the original subject around; setting the second to `$false` will prevent adding the organizer.  (Setting `-DeleteComments:$false` will also preserve the message body.)  You'll have to change this for every CR you plan inviting, and it presumes you have this kind of access to the Exchange console.  Otherwise, you have to befriend your local Exchange admin. :-)

Comment: ok thanks, but when i manually create it from my outlook it shows the subject for same calendar.

Comment: And when you say "manually create" I presume you mean, make the appt on your Outlook calendar, add room as a resource, send invite, and room accepts?  Now of course the appt as shown on *your* calendar will have the right info there, but you're saying looking directly at the room's calendar, you see same subject as in yours? That would be tough to explain...

Comment: ok, everything was working on other CR calendar, so it is calendar setting from exchange. thanks again